# Prove normal convergence of $z\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(z-k)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Mittag-Leffler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem) , in the brief sketch of the proof, it mentioned that

> $$f(z)=z\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(z-k)}$$
>
> This series converges normally on $\mathbb C$ (can be shown
> using the [M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test)) to a meromorphic function with the desired
> properties.

May I ask how to prove the convergence?

Comment: What have you tried?  What tools do you have to prove convergence?

Comment: you already mentioned the M-Test, showing normal convergence is easy to see with this tool. Remember that for any $\delta \in (0,1)$, the series $\sum_{k \in \mathbb N} \frac 1{k(k-\delta)}$ converges. A similar argument will be helpful here.

Comment: Isn't it normally on $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb N?$

Comment: @LurchiDerLurch ah, is it that $\sum_{k\in \mathbb N}\frac{1}{k(k-\delta)} < \sum_{k\in \mathbb N}\frac{1}{k(k-1)}$ converges, then for $k$ big enough, $|\sum_{k\in \mathbb N}\frac{1}{k(z-k)} | < \sum_{k\in \mathbb N}\frac{1}{k(k-Re(z))}$ then similarly it converges?

Comment: @athos you have to be careful that you don’t divide by 0